# Elegant way of implementing call multiplexing in a C++ aggregate class?

Tags: c++, aggregation, multiplexing

When multiplexing calls to many sub-objects, what is an elegant way of preventing looping-boilerplate code?

Problem description by example:

```
struct Foo {
  void Boo();
  void Hoo();
  bool IsActivated();
};

struct FooAggregator {
  ...
  void Boo();
  void Hoo();
  ...
  std::vector<Foo> m_foos;
};

FooAggregator::Boo() {
  for(size_t i=0, e=m_foos.size(); i!=e; ++i) {
    if(m_foos[i].IsActivated()) {
      m_foos[i].Boo();
    }
  }
}

FooAggregator::Hoo() {
  for(size_t i=0, e=m_foos.size(); i!=e; ++i) {
    if(m_foos[i].IsActivated()) {
      m_foos[i].Hoo();
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, the FooAggregator implements the same (similar) interface as a single Foo, iterating over all Foo objects calling their respective member functions.

As you also can see, the iteration loop is complete boilerplate, repeated for every member function of FooAggregator.

*What is an elegant way of removing the boilerplate from the implementation of FooAggregators member functions*

Comment: This ´e=m_foos.size(); i!=e´ looks like premature optimization.

Comment: @Henrik: Not it ain't. It's just idiomatic programming. All loops look the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll take Nawaz's good 1st example and simplify some more:

(Remember, I want to reduce the boilerplate, not introduce the fanciest features.)

```
// FooAggregator.h
struct FooAggregator {
    template<typename MemFn>
    void CallForEachFoo(MemFn fun);

    void Boo();
    void Hoo();
};

// FooAggregator.cpp
template<typename MemFn>
void FooAggregator::CallForEachFoo(MemFn fun) {
    BOOST_FOREACH(Foo& o, m_foos) {
      if(o.IsActivated()) {
        (o.*fun)();
      }
    }
}

void Boo() {  CallForEachFoo(&Foo::Boo); }
void Hoo() {  CallForEachFoo(&Foo::Hoo); }
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use `Boost.Bind`  as @Space_C0wb0y suggested. But if you cannot use that for whatever reason, then you can do something of this sort:

```
struct FooAggregator 
{
    typedef void (Foo::*Fun)();


    void Boo() {  CallForEach(m_foos.begin(), m_foos.end(), &Foo::Boo); }
    void Hoo() {  CallForEach(m_foos.begin(), m_foos.end(), &Foo::Hoo); }

    template<typename FwdIterator>
    void CallForEach(FwdIterator first, FwdIterator last, Fun fun)
    {
        while (first != last ) 
        { 
            if(first->IsActivated())
            {
                 (first->*fun)();
            }
            first++;
        }
    }
};
```

Or you can use `std::for_each` from `<algorithm>` as:

```
#include <algorithm>

struct FooAggregator 
{
    typedef void (Foo::*Fun)();

    void Boo() {  std::for_each(m_foos.begin(), m_foos.end(), Call(&Foo::Boo)); }
    void Hoo() {  std::for_each(m_foos.begin(), m_foos.end(), Call(&Foo::Hoo)); }

    struct Call
    {
        Fun m_fun;
        Call(Fun fun) : m_fun(fun) {}
        void operator()(Foo & foo)
        {
            if(foo.IsActivated())
            {
               (foo.*m_fun)();
            }
        }
   };    
};
```

Read about [Function object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object) to understand the second example.

---

In C++0x (i.e C++11), its very simple. You can use lamda in `std::for_each` as:

```
#include <algorithm>

struct FooAggregator 
{
    void Boo()
    {  
         std::for_each(m_foos.begin(), m_foos.end(), [](Foo &foo){ if (foo.IsActivated()) foo.Boo(); } ); 
    }

    void Hoo()
    {  
         std::for_each(m_foos.begin(), m_foos.end(), [](Foo &foo){ if (foo.IsActivated()) foo.Hoo(); } ); 
    }
    //other code
};
```

Comment: This is a step into the right direction except: 1) There's `std::foreach()` for that, 2) this would need some `std/boost::bind()` magic if the functions aren't of the same signature. Or use a lambda function, if your compiler has those.

Comment: @sbi: However, `foreach` would require wrapping the condition into an extra function.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y: That's why I brought up `bind` and lambda. @Nawaz: Great! Upvoted.

Comment: +1 for the 1st example. I don't like the 2nd two. They're to verbose. (As I wanted to reduce boilerplate, not introduce different-looking boilerplate :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Boost.Bind](http://boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/bind/bind.html) to pass a `boost::function` object into the dispatching method that specifies which method to call. Then you would only need one dispatch-method that could be called with different target methods as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Nawaz's answer is interesting, but there are alternative solutions.

First of all, you should recognize that your aggregator is very much a `Composite` pattern.

Second of all, I would go either for:

- external iteration
- a `for_each`-like member method to which a functor is passed (2 actually, because of the `const` overload).

For external iteration, read on :)

It's relatively unfortunate that C++ iterator syntax is not really geared toward "skipping" iterators, but it is achievable nonetheless.

```
class ActiveIterator {
public:
  friend class FooAggregator;

  friend bool operator==(ActiveIterator lhs, ActiveIterator rhs) {
    return lhs._it == rhs._it;
  }

  ActiveIterator& operator++() {
    this->next();
    return *this;
  }

  Foo* operator->() const { return _it::operator->(); }
  Foo& operator*() const { return *_it; }

private:
  typedef std::vector<Foo>::iterator base;
  ActivateIterator(base begin, base end): _it(begin), _end(end) {
    if (_it == _end || _it->IsActive()) { return; }
    this->next();
  }

  void next() {
    ++it; while (_it != _end && !_it->IsActive()) { ++_it; }
  }

  base _it, _end;
};
```

Then, your aggregate simply has `Begin` and `End` methods, and it's up to the caller to interact with your iterators.

*Note: you can make it template to have mutable/const implementations in one go*

External iteration remains very bulky though, because C++ lacks a generator syntax to make things simple.